# Bash grep variable as an expression

Tags: bash, variables, awk, grep, expression

I have a problem with bash. I have big log file and I must check only a part of all log. In this purpose I use those expressions:

```
cat 29.log | grep -A 999 "15/02/06-22:30"
```

or

```
awk '$1>="15/02/06-22:30" {print$0}' 29.log
```

I want to change `"15/02/06-22:30"` at `"date +%y/%m/d-%H:M"` but when I use command

```
awk '$1>="date +%y/%m/d-%H:M" {print$0}' 29.log
```

or

```
awk '$1>='date +%y/%m/d-%H:M' {print$0}' 29.log
```

nothing happens. 
Any ideas?
I need this in one command, not a script

Comment: Why can't it be a script?

Comment: Do you want the literal string `"date +%y/%m/d-%H:M"` or the output of the command `date '+%y/%m/d-%H:M'`?  You can substitute the latter into your command via the `$(date '+%y/%m/d-%H:M')` syntax.

Comment: Why can't it be a script? Because I put this command in test automation program, and harder be use a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass shell variables to AWK using the `-v` flag:

```
awk -v d="$(date '+%y/%m/%d-%H:%M')" '$1>=d' 29.log
```

Comment: But I have one more questions. What if I want save this date  in file earlier (date.txt) and execute awk command later and use date.txt like parameter.

Comment: @DamianSilkowski: Use: `-v d="$(< date.txt)"`. HTH.

Comment: man awk is sucks. I lost about 2 hours with this man and I can't find that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DamianSilkowski: I'm sorry to hear that. If it makes you feel any better though, it's actually a feature of your shell - and nothing to do with AWK. Take a look at [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). HTH.

Answer (score -1):

```
 grep -A 999 `date '+%y/%m/d-%H:M'` 29.log
```

Comment: It's work too but I like awk more than grep. But your hint is good to. Thanks.